Connecting LiDAR to Android phone
in my bachelor's project, I need to connect a LiDAR to an Android phone. I am using Valeo Scala 2, and I'm connecting it through a USB-C port. The goal is to create a simple app that gathers data from the LiDAR and saves it to a JSON file or something similar.
The phone detects the LiDAR as an Ethernet device, which is correct, but when I tried many apps similar to Wireshark on PC, I was not able to track any packets. Is it even possible to do it like this? Thank you.

See chapter 7 of the User manual:
7. ETHERNET (UDP, SUTP) DATA PROTOCOL
https://autonomoustuff.com/-/media/Images/Hexagon/Hexagon%20Core/autonomousstuff/manuals/scala-gen2-user-manual.ashx
And chapter 9:
9.2 PC settings

Make sure that no firewall is blocking the UDP protocol communication
between the sensor and your decoder PC. The sensor will Multicast its
UDP payload to the default ingress (Rx) port 22001 and to the Internet
protocol (IP) multicast group address 224.111.111.111. You should make
sure that multicast is enabled on your PC’s ethernet adapter, which
should be the default in most cases. Make sure that the UDP Rx buffer
size is at least 1MB (see the Troubleshooting Section for instructions
on this).

